# method getInputStream() in HttpURLConnection in Android always failed

Tags: android

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                "http://www.google.com").openConnection();

        InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result += inputLine;
        }
```

When it comes to urlConn.getInputStream(), it fails.
But the same code works in normal java project instead of Android project.

And I find that in Android, when it runs the first statement, urlConn is:"libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://www.google.com"

But in normal java project, it is "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://www.google.com"

Thanks!!

Exception stack:

```
11-21 21:14:01.750: I/System.out(20784): debugger has settled (1392)
11-21 21:14:56.380: W/dalvikvm(20784): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410e49d8)
11-21 21:14:56.420: E/AndroidRuntime(20784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 21:14:56.420: E/AndroidRuntime(20784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.network/com.example.network.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-21 21:14:56.420: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1969)
11-21 21:14:56.420: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1994)
11-21 21:14:56.420: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
```

I have added the INTERNET permission.

Comment: have you added the required (INTERNET) permission in your manifest? always include exception stack when ask a question

Comment: What do you mean by failed? does it throw an exception? if so, please post the logcat output.

Comment: What does it mean "fail"? Returns NULL? Throws exception? Update your question. Lack of INTERNET permission is one possibility, but you should check the logs anyway.

Comment: just google your error. there are tons of people explaining plainly enough that NetworkOnMainThreadException means that you simply cannot network on main thread (free tip : insert space before capital letters makes it look like an actual sentence)

Answer (score 3):

Ahh that famous `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` :)

Starting from *HoneyComb*, network operations - by default - are not allowed to be executed over main (UI) thread. Therefore, use `AsyncTask` or `Thread` to perform this operation on a separate thread.

Comment: It seems there's a new `NetworkOnMainThreadException` related question on SO almost every day ;)

Comment: yes, I agree... and its heart-breaking to respond the same thing over and over again :)

Comment: sorry:(...I'm reading an old book published in 2009..my god!. and thanks！

Comment: @user1842061 No worries, everyone has to learn it, it's just amazing how frequently this topic pops up. In fact, with virtually every GUI platform networking should be done in another (non-UI) thread, or asynchronously, it's not Android specific. It was Google's wise move to introduce this exception, no more unresponsive applications!

Answer (score 2):

Do not do networking on UT thread (NetworkOnMainThreadException). Use AsyncTask to avoid this exception

See this article for more details: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html